# Is it possible to access the review queue from the mobile app?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I made a New Year's resolution of making more reviews  as a way of giving back to the community. As per object, is it possible to make reviews from the mobile app? I haven't been able to access the review queue from the app. If not, would it be possible to add this feature in a future release?

PS Happy New Year !

Comment: I think it is not possible yet. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231492/are-the-review-queues-planned-for-the-ios-app and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215841/add-review-queues-to-android-app

Comment: The mobile app (android) really needs a makeup ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I wholeheartedly agree. Do you know if there is any kind of process where one can propose and/or vote for new app features?

Comment: @DeltaIV:  Maybe here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen good suggestion, but it requires at least 10 reputation to answer that question, and the association bonus doesn't count. Thus i cannot add my suggestion.

Comment: I did discover that too ... maybe some of the people in here do have that required rep at Meta, or I will try to gain it ...